# Stacking nav buttons as page resizes

Tags: html, css

I am currently a student learning HTML and CSS to become a web developer and i am having some trouble with getting my navigation buttons to properly display as the page window is resized. I want them to stack on top of one another like blocks but instead they overlap as you can see. [Webpage Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZzKY.png)

I'm sure i'm missing something obvious, but i would greatly appreciate the help.
  Thanks!

```
body {font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #523925; }

header { text-align: center;
         padding-top: 50px;
         background-image: url(coffeemug.jpg);
         height: 120px;
         font-size: 400%;
         font-family: verdana pro black;
         font-weight: bold; }

nav { text-align: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      max-height: 150px; }

nav a { text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 70px;
        border-style: solid; border-width: 4px; border-color: #16181D;
        margin-left: 5px;
        color:#523925;
        font-size: 120%; }

footer { text-align: center; 
         margin-top: 20px;
         font-size: small; }


#wrapper { width: 95%;
           margin-left: auto;
           margin-right: auto;
           background-color: #EAB987; }

.charpic {max-width: 100%; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

nav a { font-size: 100%;
        padding: 8px 50px; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `a` tags have `display: inline`, which lets them display side by side and fit as ends up not respecting margins very well. As noted in a previous answer, changing them to `display: block` will get them to respect margins, but prevent them from sitting side by side unless you add additional logic.

Probably the simplest change to get the behavior that I *think* you're looking for is to make them `display: inline-block`, which will continue to lay them out side by side but treat them as block elements that won't overlap as they end up wrapping.  This would look like:

```
nav a { 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 70px;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 4px; border-color: #16181D;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color:#523925;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 120%; 
}
```

You could also do this by using flexbox, making `nav` a flex parent with `display: flex` and then using flex properties to determine layout. This would be a bit more of a change, but I think probably get you a nicer solution. As an example, if you wanted to have them overflow when necessary and be centered each line, you could do:

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Yup that actually did it! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it solved it for you. Can you approve the answer as correct?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Still new to the site!

Answer (score 0):

try adding display: block; to the a  element, like so:

```
nav a { text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 70px;
    border-style: solid; border-width: 4px; border-color: #16181D;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color:#523925;
display: block;
    font-size: 120%; }
```

Comment: No that only makes the nav buttons show up as a stack of horizontal bars going across the entire page. I want the nav buttons to stay as boxes as i've coded them but then as i resize the page they will stack on top of one another.